# ios how to do reloadData after executing Block

Tags: ios, asynchronous, block

```
    for (int i = 0; i < self.dataArray.count; i++) {
        DYDeviceModel *object = self.dataArray[i];
        [[AlinkSDK sharedManager] invokeWithMethod:@"mtop.openalink.app.core.device.privatedata.retrieve" params:@{@"uuid":object.uuid, @"dataKey":@"colorType"} completionHandler:^(AlinkResponse * _Nonnull response) {

            if (response.successed) {
                NSString *lastColorType = [[response dataObject] objectForKey:@"dataString"];
                if (lastColorType == nil)  {
                    lastColorType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 0];
                }
                NSLog(@" %@", lastColorType);
                NSInteger type = [lastColorType integerValue];
                [self.selectedImage addObject:_colorArray[type]];
                //                [self.tableView reloadData];
            } else {
                NSString *lastColorType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 0];
                NSInteger type = [lastColorType integerValue];
                [self.selectedImage addObject:_colorArray[type]];
                //                [self.tableView reloadData];

            }
        }];
    }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
```

I need to do tableView reloadData after executing block, but block is asynchronous. I tried many methods but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to solve this? Thanks very much

Comment: Use `dispatch_group` and reload the table view after the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: I tried this way but it doesn't work, can you tell me in detail? thanks, I'm afraid my method is wrong.

Comment: Update your question with your attempts to use `dispatch_group`. Clearly explain what issues you are having with it.

Comment: Unrelated but the code in your `else` is odd. What's the point of creating a string from a literal `0` and then converting that string to an integer? Why not simply do `NSInteger type = 0;` ? And in the `if`, replace `lastColorType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 0];` with: `lastColorType = @"0";`.

Comment: I find these problems,thanks